# Schema file does not reflect table removal migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

I removed several tables in my Rails database by running `rails generate migration RemoveObjects` and then ran `rake db:migrate` to complete the migration, however I am not seeing the change reflected in my schema.rb file.

What else should I do to remove references to these object from that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: Running that command didn't remove the objects from my schema file

Comment: This will create the schema file from the database. So maybe your migration did not work? Could you try rolling back the migration and running it again.

Comment: You're right, I looked into the files that "rails generate migration RemoveObjects" generated and they are all basically blank... should I build these migrations from scratch?

Comment: So I went ahead and edited the schema.rb file and then did `rake db:migrate` followed by `rake db:schema:dump` and schema file was not regenerated. So I guess those tables were deleted after all and the change wasn't reflected in that file.

Comment: The "rails generate migration RemoveObjects" will just create the migration file. You have to write the actual migration steps in that file. You can find more details here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 1):

This migration will!  You probably made a mistake inside the migration itself.

```
class DropTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :table_name
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```